# Export CSV file to FTP site using SQL

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how to export CSV file to FTP site in SQL management studio? 
I am currently using 
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use \ftp://213.32.32 \user:fjdowj ddfdf'
But it doesn't work at all
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not work at all? 213.32.32 is not a valid IP address, for one thing.

Comment: Thanks for asking that. The SQL query doesn't work. I am really sorry, I faked the IP address. But I tested the real FTP site. It is working fine. I was able to upload files or delete files. I just can't export CSV files to ftp site. I have a SQL job which executes SQL query every day and export csv files to ftp site. The problem now is that I don't know how to establish the connection to ftp site in SQL

Answer (score 0):

you can try CLR stored procedure to generate CSV file and export to FTP site.

Generating CSV file to a path is given below:

```
public static void GenerateCSVFile(SqlString queryToGetData, SqlString folderPath)
        {
            string sqlCommand;
            string filePath;
            try
            {

                    sqlCommand = queryToGetData.ToString();
                    filePath = folderPath.ToString() + "\\GeneratedFile" + ".csv";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                 "context connection=true"))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand,connection);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        table.Load(reader);

                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
                        List<string> rows = new List<string>();

                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
                        }

                        builder.Append(string.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray())).Append("\n");

                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();

                            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                            {
                                object item = row[column];

                                currentRow.Add(item.ToString());
                            }

                            rows.Add(string.Join(",", currentRow.ToArray()));
                        }

                        builder.Append(string.Join("\n", rows.ToArray()));

                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                        {
                            writer.Write(builder.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Once you generate file, you can use the below approach to load to FTP path. 
[FTP Directly in SQL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192558/FTP-directly-in-SQL-Using-SQL-CLR)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to generate CSV files but I am having a problem transferring CSV files to the FTP site. I read your FTP directly in SQL article. I have some questions about it. I am not sure the getting started steps. Can tell me more about it for example how to create a visual classic library? I was also curious is there any other way to get connected to a FTP site in SQL? Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

`xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default (for very good reasons) on all recent versions of SQL Server.  You could re-enable it manually (and I encourage you NOT to), but then you'd need an ftp command line tool to do the upload-- I don't think that `net use` command is going to do the trick.  If you did manage to map an ftp end point as a drive with `net use` as the SQL Server service user, you would still need to achieve copying the file from SSMS to the filesystem on the server before running the FTP job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not manage to map the fit site using net use in SQL. This is really my problem. I would appreciate it if you have any idea of connecting to FTP site in SQL so that I can export CSV file to FTP site.